# windows 8.1 taskhostex.exe memory errors

Tags: windows-8.1, memory

I am able to login to my windows 8.1 machine but as soon as Desktop appears I get memory errors from taskhostex.exe

[image]

After I cancel it a series of errors come up one by one, new one comes after I cancel the first one, and if I press ok anywhere, the system restarts. following is screenshot of one of those errors.

[image]

**UPDATE**

as I am not able to interact with my pc due to this error I tried to make a bootable usb of Ubuntu and then select "try Ubuntu" option so that I can atleast recover my data on hard disk. I am not able to open any disk drive in Ubuntu because my windows hasn't been shutdown properly yet, then I tried to shut it down from the lockscreen , and its taking forever to shutdown or restart, but it isn't completing.

**UPDATE 2**
I made a windows 8.1 bootable usb and tried to repair pc with it, it says:

> The drive where windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.

and when I try to upgrade my existing windows 8.1 installation, it asks for the key and after that it says to restart and run windows normally and then upgrade. I cant even get into my windows how can I upgrade from there? :/

Comment: 0xc000009c = STATUS_DEVICE_DATA_ERROR. so check the HDD cables and the HDD itself with a diag tool from the manufacture

Comment: actually its a laptop, so how can I check the cables?

Comment: there is no cable. check the HDD with a diag tool. Also removing it and insert the HDD again. This can also help.

Comment: this error pops up as soon as I see my desktop and I am not able to use or interact with pc apart from pressing ok or cancel on the error

Comment: please see update version of the question

Comment: run a Linux Live CD/DVD, they also include HDD diag tools

Comment: I may be wrong, but the first thing I'd look into when I saw these errors was if I had contracted a virus.

Comment: how would I do that? @music2myear

Comment: I am not able to shutdown my laptop, I have to force restart it, is there a way I can shut it down somehow so I am able to access the HDD through Ubuntu? Ubuntu doesn't let me access the disk drives because it says windows was either hibernated or it hasn't been properly shut down

Comment: Can you get into Safe Mode and then shut down? Have you tried the built-in Windows repair tools? Pressing F8 on boot may bring these up.

Comment: For virus cleanup you should check this exhaustive answer: https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: @music2myear this has nothing to do with virus. the drive has issues.

Comment: i am not even able to boot into safe mode, can anyone of you guyx tell me how can I recover my data I am really worried and I have really important data in my drive.